# How to know what path to specify in Node for require

Tags: node.js, require

All:

When I use Express.js(but I believe this is more of a Node question),  if I want to import some modules, I need to use require(module path).

But I am a little confused what root path should be used for each require, are they all same to the path we execute the node command?

Sometime, It works when I use require("../modelname") while sometimes require("./modelname") even I did not change the modelname.js location.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look on this documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together There you will find the logic for files loading

Comment: @apsillers  The only thing I changed is I run node in different directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a directory where you want to access `modelname` there are two scenarios given below

1. if `modelname` is in the same directory then you can use `require("./modelname")`
2. if calling directory is different and one level above to your `modelname` directory then you have to use `require("../modelname")`.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you could help me with another question: I searched some posts about how to debug node. Which way do you use for debug? I am just trying to find way as easy as chrome console.

Answer (score 3):

Node documentation provides a [pseudo-code algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for how it resolves the path for `require()`

To sum up:

```
require(X) from module at path Y
If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
   b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)

LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
1. If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP
2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP
4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP

LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
1. If X/package.json is a file,
   a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
   b. let M = X + (json main field)
   c. LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP
```

Comment: So this means the path is related to the file location which run require,  rather than the location run the node command?

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you could help me with another question: I searched some posts about how to debug node. Which way do you use for debug? I am just trying to find way as easy as chrome console.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `require( 'express' )`, node will begin in your current folder, and step up the file tree until it locates a folder that has a `package.json` inside it.

Once it finds this file, it will check for a `node_modules` folder and look for `node_modules/express`. It will then follow the instructions in `node_modules/express/package.json` as to how to go about including the module.

If you want to require your own code that lacks a `package.json`, you'd do something like this.

`require( './router' )`

or

`require( '../middleware/site-data' )`

In the first example, the `.` refers to the folder the file doing the import is in, and will import either `./router.js` or `./router/index.js`, depending on which exists. In `require`, `.` is effectively translated into `__dirname + '/'`.

In the second example, the `..` refers to the parent of the directory the importing file is in. In `require`, `..` is effectively translated into `__dirname + '/../'`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, what if I have both router folder(with index.js in it) and router.js, which one will it import if use resuire("../router")?

Comment: @Kuan The default will be `router.js`

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you could help me with another question:  I searched some posts about how to debug node. Which way do you use for debug? I am just trying to find way as easy as chrome console.

Comment: @Kuan Better to make ask a separate question, but I typically just use `console.log` a lot, bad as that is.

Comment: Thanks. sometimes I feel the console is really hard to show object, and that is why I am looking for other tools

Answer (score 0):

use webstorm tool where you have debugging facility like we have in eclipse, start your application in debug mode and put breakpoints.